# Make an external Script available to all members of qooxdoo Object

Tags: javascript, d3.js, qooxdoo

So I have been making a web app in the qooxdoo framework that utilised the d3 library. At the moment, every function which needs to use the d3 library works like this:

```
myFunction : function() {
    var req = new qx.bom.request.Script();
    req.onload = this.myActualFunction(); //calls function when script loads
    req.open("GET","http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js" );
    req.send();
}
```

It seems verbose to have to call the script loader for lots of different functions*. We could, and eventually probably will, switch to using d3 from a local directory. Nevertheless, it seems like there are lots of times when you would like to use a script loader to make a script available to, say, every member function of an object. Is there someway that I can achieve that? If I passed the script loader around like a variable, does that mean that every function which has it in scope gets access to the library?

The Manual did not appear very helpful on this topic.

*I presume that qooxdoo arranges to cache the script - it seems to be pretty good at those type of optimisations, though I have no specific knowledge of how the script loaders are treated in the compiled version.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach of handling an external library is to create a Qooxdoo wrapper which will be a first-class citizen in the dependency management process. Qooxdoo internally makes use of this approach, e.g. [Sizzle](https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/blob/master/framework/source/class/qx/bom/Selector.js), [Mustache](https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/blob/master/framework/source/class/qx/bom/Template.js), etc. Luckily for you there's already [a contribution for D3](http://qooxdoo.org/contrib/catalog/#QxD3). Though you can make your own wrapper without a hassle.

You can also, use [`add-script`](http://manual.qooxdoo.org/3.5.1/pages/tool/generator/generator_config_ref.html#add-script) to "link" the library to the document but I see this way mostly disadvantageous.